# How to use PCA in c#

Tags: c#, pca

I am using Microsoft Visual C# 2010. I am trying to recognize human motion and want to use pca to reduce dimensionality.  Can anyone tell me how to add built in class: PrincipalComponentAnalysis.c.

Comment: Your question is excessively vague, and you're not likely to find a lot of help here without refining it significantly. What exactly are you trying to do? What have you tried? What happened when you tried? What didn't work as you expected? What other places have you looked at to get information? Why wasn't that information sufficient? Details like that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're trying to add a C library into C# and use it in the same way you do (for example) System.Windows, you're going to have a lot of difficulty, because that's simply not possible.

If you want to call C DLLs from C#, I'd take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx) article.

Comment: does emguCV provide API/function for PCA

Comment: @GeetanjaliKale I have absolutely no idea what emguCV is.